# VMware Server Rich(Fat) client management app

Tags: vmware-server

With VMWare Server 1.x there was a nice fat client application for managing the server. Is that still available and functional with 2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VMware 1.x client management application is no longer available for version 2.0. It's web-based now at `http://serverip:8333`.

However, a reasonable workaround is to use the vSphere client application for ESX 3.x/4.x and connect to `serverip:8333` instead of `serverip`.

Comment: The web based management application is largely unuseable. It does nothing but throw errors in current Firefox and IE. It works well in Chrome, but there is no console plugin. It's free so I'm not complaining too loudly, but one presumes that they offer a free version in order to up sell. The fact that you can't manage the free version would seem to make up selling to the commercial version something of a chore.

Comment: You can simply download the VMWare Infrastructure client and use it to manage your VMWare Server 2.0 servers as long as you append the "8333" to the IP. It works better than the web client.

Comment: When I try that with my existing VMware Infrastructure client, I get the "standard" message that it wants to download files from the server, then immediately errors.

Comment: I'm sorry. It works with the old VMWare VI 2.5 client. With version 4, that functionality went away. See the end of the tread at the following link for a workaround: http://communities.vmware.com/message/1653290?tstart=15